# Get View height based on margin constraints after runtime Swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a circle in the centre of a screen with a margin constraint of `50` on either end. Hence, the width of the circle is dependent on the screen size.

So, what I tried was this:

**Approach 1**

I set up the margins in the storyboard to define the circle width (`50` on left and right)

Then I used the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var helpButHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var helpBut: UIButton!
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
helpButHeight.constant = helpBut.frame.size.width
```

This didn't work.

Since the screen width is `400`, and the margin is `50` on either end, then `helpBut.frame.size.width` should have given me `300`.

Instead it gave me `46`.

**Approach 2**

This was my work-around:

ViewDidLoad:

```
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    helpButHeight.constant = screenSize.width - 100
```

because `100 = 50 + 50`, the two margins.

Works fine !

**Question**

Why did I have to do this? Why did the first approach not work? Why `46` and not `300`?

Comment: Are you doing this `helpButHeight.constant = helpBut.frame.size.width` in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: yes, sorry, I'll make that clear

Comment: What don't you just set the Aspect Ration to 1:1 and then set leading and trailing constraints to 50, and you can center it vertically?

Comment: Of Course, nice idea, but still curious why the my approach didn't work

Comment: Did you try to update the layout? This can be achieved by calling `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` after you set the contraints

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is that constraints haven't kicked in, in the `viewDidLoad` function. The lifecycle looks something like

- `viewDidLoad` -- Constraints haven't set
- `viewWillAppear` -- Constraints haven't set
- `viewWillLayoutSubviews` -- Constraints are setting
- `viewDidLayoutSubviews` -- Constraints are set
- `viewDidAppear` -- Constraints are set

Comment: Great, so I should basically move my code into `viewDidLayout`

Comment: Except it's called `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

If you want any view to be in center just put the horizontal/vertical center constraint...No code required.. If you want to have padding just put the left and right constraints...Just to remind you don't use both of them together...It'll break...